# Make Raspberry Pi Automatically Upload A File to a Server With Requests

Tags: python, csv, web-applications, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I currently have a file upload page at a public link, the upload page has a button which prompts a user to upload a csv file and then hit submit for the webpage to use the data they uploaded.

[image]

I want to have my raspberry pi use requests to go onto this web page and post the csv automatically, is there an easy way to do this? Do I need a bot or something?

Edit:

For example, in the following code, how can I edit that so that it uploads this stored.csv file to the webapp automatically?

```
#!/user/bin/env python
import serial
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#Port recieving from Arduino
port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"

s1 = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
s1.flushInput()

#Dictionary of measures to be stored in csv, tracking input history from arduino
#stored = pd.read_csv('stored.csv', names= . 
['moisture']).moisture.tolist()[1:]

stored = {
    'moisture': [],
    'time': [],
    'pump': [],
    'light': [],
    'temperature': []
}

previousTime = 0

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    s1.flushInput()
    inputString = s1.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(inputString)


    if(inputString[0] == '<'):
        mystr = inputString.split('<')[1].split(',')
        moist = int(mystr[0])

        stored['moisture'].append(int(moist)) #moisture level
        stored['time'].append(now)
        stored['pump'].append('running') #if arduino is pumping still
        stored['light'].append('5V')
        stored['temperature'].append('25 Celsius')
        df = pd.DataFrame(stored, columns=['moisture', 'time', 'pump', 'light', 'temperature'])
        df.to_csv('stored.csv', index=False)

        # Add time delay

        #moist = int(pd.read_csv('stored.csv').tail(1)['moisture'][0])
        threshold = 1000

    if(moist > threshold):
        pump_state = '1'
    else:
        pump_state = '0'
        #string.charAt(0) = '1'
        string = '<' + pump_state + ',1,0>'
        string_encoded = string.encode()
        s1.write(string_encoded)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

And here is the html for the form:

```
    <form action="{% url "upload_my_file" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code so we can base an answer on it.

Comment: @KlausD. to be honest I don't even know where to begin with the requests part, I spent a lot of time coding up the actual website and making this form work for my purposes (graphing) and this is the final piece having the pi upload to the website through the interface automatically, I did some research on requests, but I couldn't find a good example of a post that has to interface with a form like this which has led me here, I have a sad 3 lines of code on this part but they aren't much to work from

Comment: @KlausD.                                                                                                   
  `import requests,
    url = 'http://mywebsite.com/upload/',
    r = requests.post(url, data="stored.csv")` even just someone to verbally explain where to go with it would be a big help

Comment: To help you we need to see the source of the form so that we know how browsers will send the file. Alternatively you can use the networking tab of the developer tools of Firefox/Chrome to see the data being sent, hopefully it will help you to replicate this with requests. And yet another solution is to show us the code that is receiving this file to see how it needs it.

Comment: @QuentinPradet So the project is written in django, here is the github to that code: https://github.com/ltdiadams/Garden-Bot-3000. When you say source of the form are you looking to see the view? Or the html code? Since the pi is separate from the computer which I designed the webapp on would it be better to use networking in chrome?

Comment: I mean the HTML code of the form, yes. Please add it to the question

Comment: @QuentinPradet okay will do!!

Comment: @DanielDecker is it possible to see it rendered? By looking at the source from your browser. BTW the CSRF protection is going to be a problem here.

Comment: @QuentinPradet Here is the public link to the upload form http://ltdiadams.pythonanywhere.com/upload/ (web security is next on the list :P) is there another way to get the stored.csv file and automatically upload it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Django website is protected against CSRF attacks, so we first need to fetch a CSRF cookie and use it when submitting the file:

```py
import requests

with open("stored.csv", "rb") as f:
    s = requests.Session()
    # fetch the CSRF cookie
    r1 = s.get("http://ltdiadams.pythonanywhere.com/upload/")
    assert r1.status_code == 200
    csrf_token = r1.cookies["csrftoken"]
    print("got csrf token", csrf_token)

    # post stored.csv
    r2 = s.post(
        "http://ltdiadams.pythonanywhere.com/upload/",
        data={"csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token},
        files={"file": f},
    )
    print(r2.status_code)
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure that out, thank you so so so very much I was having a lot of trouble with it

Comment: @DanielDecker Glad I could help!